# size of boost uuid in string returns 36

Tags: boost, uuid, boost-uuid

I am trying to generate 16 character uuid string using boost::uuid but it returns 36 characters.

```
boost::uuids::uuid uid == boost::random_generator()();
std::cout << size of uid:" << uid.size << std::endl; //always 16
std::stringstream ss;
ss<< uid;
std::string s = ss.str();
std::cout << "size of uid:" << s.size() << std::endl; // always 36
```

How do I get 16 character uuid string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html#Byte%20Extraction), this piece of code should give you a 16 character string:

```
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>            // uuid class
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp> // generators
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>         // streaming operators etc.
boost::uuids::uuid uid = boost::random_generator()();
std::string s(uid.size());
std::copy(u.begin(), u.end(), s.begin());
```

However it's not an ASCII string but a byte string. As ASCII can represent bytes with 2 hex characters, UUID in ASCII have 32 characters plus 4 separators, 36.       So you already have the right code :)

Comment: I already tried that but it doesn't copy ascii characters. it has some binary characters which I can't print. Event I tried to print in std::hex but still couldn't read/see. try printing using std::out.

Comment: See my edit, you can't represent UUID with 16 ASCII characters

Comment: I am not sure why would it add 4 separators but it does make sense to convert unsigned char to char would take 2 bytes so it requires 32.

Comment: @rjoshi it's the standard ASCII representation of a UUID (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid)